# How to solve implicit any type to index type error in typescript?

Tags: typescript

How to solve this error

- "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type?"

What is the reason behind this error? What is index type? The code is given below

```
const getPast = action => {
  const presentToPast = {
    approve: 'approved',
    reject: 'rejected',
    edit: 'edited',
    create: 'created'
  };

  return presentToPast[action];
};
```

Comment: Please provide your code so we can help you understand what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

i would create custom type for presentToPast

```
type presentToPastType = {
  approve: 'approved',
  reject: 'rejected',
  edit: 'edited',
  create: 'created',
};

const getPast = (action: keyof presentToPastType) => {
  const presentToPast = {
    approve: 'approved',
    reject: 'rejected',
    edit: 'edited',
    create: 'created',
  };

  return presentToPast[action];
};
```

or workaround would be

```
const getPast = (action: keyof typeof presentToPast) => {
  const presentToPast = {
    approve: 'approved',
    reject: 'rejected',
    edit: 'edited',
    create: 'created',
  };

  return presentToPast[action];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow Sayan,

The problem on your code is that you are using a parameters (action) which is not typed, you can try it:

```
const getPast = ( action: string ) => {
  const presentToPast = {
    approve: 'approved',
    reject: 'rejected',
    edit: 'edited',
    create: 'created'
  };

  return presentToPast[action];
};

console.log(getPast('approve'));// gonna log : approved
```