# TypeScript: Type error when sorting an array of objects

Tags: typescript

Ive got some data and an interface...

```
  const data = [
    { category: 'Fish', age: 10, country: 'United Kingdom' },
    { category: 'Fish', age: 9, country: 'United Kingdom' },
    { category: 'Fish', age: 8, country: 'United Kingdom' },
    { category: 'Fish', age: 7, country: 'United Kingdom' },
    { category: 'Dogs', age: 10, country: 'China' },
    { category: 'Dogs', age: 9, country: 'China' },
    { category: 'Dogs', age: 8, country: 'China' },
    { category: 'Dogs', age: 7, country: 'China' },
  ];

  interface CountProps {
    category: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;
  }
```

And the function with the errors is...

```
  const sort = (dataToSort: CountProps[], onlyShow: string, sortBy: string | number, ascDesc: -1 | 1) => {
      return dataToSort
        .filter((v) => v.category === onlyShow)
        .sort((a, b) =>
          +ascDesc ? a[sortBy] - b[sortBy] : b[sortBy] - a[sortBy]
//                   ^ Error     ^ Error     ^ Error     ^ Error
        );
  };
  const sortedData = sort(data, 'birds', 'age', -1);
```

The error I get is

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'ReactText' can't be used to index type 'CountProps'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'CountProps'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: It's telling you that you might not be able to index `sortBy` with `a` and `b` because `CountProps` might not have an appropriate property (e.g., pass `"randomString"` in for `sortBy`).  Instead you want `sortBy` to be annotated as something like `keyof CountProps`, but that leads to other problems you should fix.  You are possibly subtracting `string` values, which isn't useful (probably just results in `NaN`). And then there's the test for `ascDesc`; the only falsy number is `0`, so unless you want `ascDesc` to behave one way for `0` and another for all other numbers, you've got a bad test.

Comment: for ascDesc I intended to pass in -1 or 1 as arguments to the sort function

Comment: then `ascDesc` should maybe be annotated as type `-1 | 1` instead of `number`, and then your test needs to look like, e.g., `ascDesc === 1 ? x : -x` or `ascDesc >= 0 ? x : -x` or even `ascDesc * x`.  This feels "homeworky" to me; I'm not sure if I'm doing a disservice by making specific suggestions.

Comment: I think the linked question doesn't quite fit here because we probably want to prevent weird `sortBy` values like `"randomString"`.  Instead, `keyof CountProps` is more fitting.

Comment: Maybe [How to solve implicit any type to index type error in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733732/how-to-solve-implicit-any-type-to-index-type-error-in-typescript) is a closer duplicate, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56735692/2887218) answer using `keyof` as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your interface has the following properties: `category`, `age`, and `color`, and not *any* arbitrary `string` or `number`. Therefore, the **type of `sortBy` should be a key of the interface**, and not just a generic union type of `string | number`:

```
sortBy: keyof CountProps
```

Also, since `a[sortBy]` and `b[sortBy]` can potentially return both a string and a number, you cannot use arithmetic comparison to perform sorting, i.e. `a[sortBy] - b[sortBy]`. Instead, you need to use `>` or `<` to perform comparison.

Note: Since your `ascDesc` only accepts `-1` or `+1`, we don't need to use the unary operator to convert it, i.e. `+ascDesc` is not necessary. Assuming that `+1` indicates you want to sort ascendingly and `-1` descendingly, the following code should work as expected:

```
const sort = (dataToSort: CountProps[], onlyShow: string, sortBy: keyof CountProps, ascDesc: -1 | 1) => {
  return dataToSort
    .filter((v) => v.category === onlyShow)
    .sort((a, b) => {
      let aValue = a[sortBy];
      let bValue = b[sortBy];

      // Advice: you might want to convert values if uppercase if they're string
      // If you are dealing with multiple languages, might want to use `.toLocaleUpperCase()`
      if (typeof aValue === 'string') {
        aValue = aValue.toUpperCase();
      }
      if (typeof bValue === 'string') {
        bValue = bValue.toUpperCase();
      }

      if (aValue > bValue) {
        return ascDesc;
      }
      if (aValue < bValue) {
        return ascDesc * -1;
      }

      return 0;
    });
  };
```

[See proof-of-concept example of your code on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtAUDXMDeMwSApgOYgBOAngFwwDkAYgJYQAWDANDAmSfQCMABh6gArmCg16DAKpgWUEnBgBpFmDJwQAWwYwAvlxx5CxZRRmNWHbr370AnGJCTpdRgqUr1m7XoGxqa45qRWnsxsnDx8AjAAHK7u1vKKyqoaWjr6RiZ4BEThVJG2MQ7xAOzJUqneGX7ZgXkhhRbkJbIAIiBkEPZxQqJEbrWRAMLsmghB+WZFlp2MPX0DjjAuIykTU2AzLQVhi6kr-bHrSVtjspPTs61HHSe9ZxX01VceN7v7wbgAugBuLCmTTKSgAMwQwBIMHGoygAAVKCAAA4QAitdoRejQSj+YEFQYwMDiXQAIxIlEJeAk1xgeIJpkMINwoEgsAgVFg6AAFIhkAAVEAAZW59Hh7mRaIgGH+PHAABtqCL2CAAO646T+HhcyhQABCngA1iRqCAIXCEdL0bEIMAuiR7fQALSCGAAHxgggAlGgAHyY3CUEhQcSUMDwJAIYVi-WtAB0EJYivBvN5ADc-ahAxmE9iSmhUOglSq1eqfYm9VB0wgeOTs4H8K1cIrQ7wAGoIRXiWHoBAYatGoEtmBt2Dkrs9vswcmD7nD4GjgD0y5gAEE4BmWDD6ObxDBdCwyOxYOqEFIYFAQCMwBmqbAM93exiWJbxKjUVTiBBYW+r+wZoMCGDLaloK5rgAkpa+68CBcAkN2-gwOqSjsIe4ipiwqJtmOF5kOIcQQDwR4nmeF6wNeMDiL+MAAAYJteAAyIDEG2ciflS4wIL+vI+nRo7-ryUDUF+Fqds+fbFowjJaAwfrNgURJTr2aASdOjEgBxX6UNxvE+jSBQskpMBCSJYmWpOklFugDCyWQ8lBiZs4qTOVkade2lcTxJB8YZeAsoJlq8ggrkwIG7m9gpo7BqG4aRjxDpOsA-m4MZSlCaF1kADwuZJ0XOTAIZhhGvD2o69owAAVDAbqpUYrJKcV8UwMI-mGAZzJLquMBxrAyYcE6s7UDAXQAKIiuMY0AHJdJB00AOIVFg7Jcm2CaKr0vLVvy0Y8FEdj7XE9huj6nVYD1fUwANgEYuSI3rpNM1zYty2rSA62bWQ23crtyD7WU9gMMdPC+p1QA).

Comment: That feeling when the penny drops, thank you so much!

Comment: @Bill No problem! I've added an additional comment in my code: you might want to force `toUpperCase()` for string comparisons.

Comment: the `const aValue` needed to be `let`, but yes really nice detail

Comment: @Bill Yup that was fixed